# Render Result Zoom Artefacts

Tags: image

I'm honestly not even sure what the name of the render result's window is, but whatever it is, I often notice artefacts when zoomed into the result. Horizontal/vertical banding, clearly as an artefact of pixel interpolation that isn't 1:1. Sometimes this happens when rendering at 720p, ex:

[image: horizontal handing on default resolution]

And also when zooming in on any render:

[image: less clear banding]

This is a little less clear to see, but the edges of the wireframe lines are all jagged, at regular intervals.

Just to be clear, this happens regardless of what I render, here's the default scene rendered (with eevee) and zoomed in (with the mousewheel), notice the jagged edges of the cube:

[image: default cube edge]

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the viewer, not the render as when I view the image zoomed in with a 3rd party viewer the artefacts are not present.

Frankly I find this really annoying, is there any way to fix it? Even just what it would be called would be nice for google searches, as I'm kind of in the dark here.

Thank you!

Comment: @vklidu the scene doesn't matter, I added in an example with the default cube scene to show that. After looking through those links I just wanted to clarify again that this is not a rendering issue, it is an image viewing issue. I'll find better tags if I can.

Comment: Now I understood, than your issue seems to be for bug tracker, there is nothing we can help here. Also on bug tracker m not sure if something like this will be accepted ... I see jaggling edge, but similar can be seen in other apps (I tried Ph with less prominent effect) ... in blender there is a bit weird kind of recalculation visible even on close view like pixels are changing aspect ratio https://imgur.com/WLAXEN2 ... hm

Comment: @vklidu Thank you, yeah this kind of thing is inherent to resizing, you always get artefacts it's just that these are some of the worst I've seen, so I was hoping there was a fix. Does this not happen for everyone?